# Excel VBA create Data Model connection for Power Pivot table to get distinct values - error

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot, datamodel, distinct-values

In a macro, I'm trying to get distinct values to count, based on 2 criteria. Before, I've used a formula in an external report to add the counts **=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(**. This works for most of the vendors but when the raw data it's counting from becomes too big on other vendors it errors and only shows 1 or 0.

I've switched to trying to add the raw data table to a pivot table and add it to a data model in the same workbook as the raw data table so that I can easily get a distinct count column and then use **GETPIVOTDATA** to add the counts to rows in the external report. This is all part of a larger macro. This works fine on some vendors, others error on creating the data model connection. **"Run-time error 1004: An issue with the Data Model is preventing Microsoft Excel from opening this workbook. Try restarting Microsoft Excel."**

I've tried to clear connections before creating a new connection and new pivot table, but I still get the error. When I stop the macro to test adding a power pivot table and adding to the model manually, all my PowerPivot options are greyed out as well as the option of adding it to a data model when trying to add it through the normal Pivot Table option.

This is my first time using PowerPivot in a macro but I cannot seem to find an easier solution to get distinct values when using a big data set without it hanging or giving just a "1" or "0".

Current code:

```
    Dim wsPivotModel As Worksheet
    Dim SDCPivotCache As PivotCache
    Dim PvtSDCmodel As PivotTable
    Dim SDCconnection As WorkbookConnection
    Set wsPivotModel = MainWB.Sheets.Add
    
    ' delete existing internal connections if necessary
    For Each SDCconnection In MainWB.Connections
        If SDCconnection.Type = xlConnectionTypeWORKSHEET Then SDCconnection.Delete
    Next SDCconnection
    
    'Create new connection
    Set SDCconnection = MainWB.Connections.Add2("WorksheetConnection_" & MainWB.Name & "!Table_SDCdata", "", _
        "WORKSHEET;" & DataPath & "\" & MainWB.Name, MainWB.Name & "!Table_SDCdata", 7, True, False)
    
    'create and configure new pivotcache
    Set SDCPivotCache = MainWB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=SDCconnection, Version:=6)
    With SDCPivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    End With
    
    'Create and configure new pivottable
    Set PvtSDCmodel = SDCPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsPivotModel.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:="PvtSDCmodel", DefaultVersion:=6)


    With wsPivotModel.PivotTables("PvtSDCmodel")
        .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels

        With .CubeFields("[Table_SDCdata].[Region]")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .CubeFields("[Table_SDCdata].[Format]")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
        
        .CubeFields.GetMeasure "[Table_SDCdata].[Site]", xlCount, "Count of Site"
        .AddDataField .CubeFields("[Measures].[Count of Site]"), "Count of Site"
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
        
        With .PivotFields("[Measures].[Count of Site]")
            .Caption = "Distinct Count of Site"
            .Function = xlDistinctCount
        End With
        
    End With
       
'Get store format count in province from SDC
    Dim ref As Variant
    Dim sFormula As String
    
    ref = "[" & MainWB.Name & "]" & wsPivotModel.Name
    sFormula = "=GETPIVOTDATA(""[Measures].[Distinct Count of Site]"",'" & ref & "'!$A$1,""[Table_SDCdata].[Region]"",""[Table_SDCdata].[Region].&[""&[@Region]&""]"",""[Table_SDCdata].[Format]"",""[Table_SDCdata].[Format].&[""&[@Format]&""]"")"
        
    With wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged")
        With .ListColumns("Total Number of Stores : In Province").DataBodyRange
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Formula = sFormula
            .Value = .Value
        End With
```

Any suggestions on why this error is happening and greying out all my options afterward?
Or if any other suggestions on how to easily get the distinct count from a large amount of data without it failing if Power Pivot is not going to work (which is should)?

Comment: Do you have created as MEASURE in PP for DISTINCTCOUNT? If yes take al look to Excel-Functions CUBEMEMBER() and CUBEVALUE(). With this functions you do not need a PIvotTable, you can access directly to the Datamodel.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, I will look into it but first I need to solve the issue of creating the connection for the data model which is the main problem, where I get the error.